# Magento 2 Error filtering template?

Tags: magento2, template, stock, inventory

After installed module we are getting one error message called

> "Error filtering template: You cannot define a correlation name
>   'stock' more than once"

Mentioned with below code. Can anyone advise how to solve?

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Interjar_ConfigurableChildVisibility
 * @author Interjar Ltd
 * @author Josh Carter <josh@interjar.com>
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Interjar\ConfigurableChildVisibility\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\BaseSelectProcessorInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status as StockStatus;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status as StockStatusResource;

class StockStatusBaseSelectProcessor implements BaseSelectProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var StockConfigurationInterface
     */
    private $stockConfig;

    /**
     * @var StockStatusResource
     */
    private $stockStatusResource;

    /**
     * @param StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfig
     * @param StockStatusResource $stockStatusResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfig,
        StockStatusResource $stockStatusResource
    ) {
        $this->stockConfig = $stockConfig;
        $this->stockStatusResource = $stockStatusResource;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(Select $select)
    {
        if (!$this->stockConfig->isShowOutOfStock()) {
            $select->joinInner(
                ['stock' => $this->stockStatusResource->getMainTable()],
                sprintf(
                    'stock.product_id = %s.entity_id',
                    BaseSelectProcessorInterface::PRODUCT_TABLE_ALIAS
                ),
                []
            )->where(
                'stock.stock_status = ?',
                StockStatus::STATUS_IN_STOCK
            );
        }

        return $select;
    }
}
```

Comment: what for is the `s` in `%s.entity_id`? I think the error comes from there

Answer (score 0):

Print and debug the `$select` , it seems that `stock` or `'stock' => $this->stockStatusResource->getMainTable()` has already been in the select query and you are trying to join it again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ansgy mishra so can u show me how to change that process method.?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Share the printed result of the query.